# Enterprise level analytics software to test and monitor usability

Tags: software-testing, analytics

We are developing a hospital management software,We need to monitor that software after the deployments..What are the best tools we can use..Better it can host our server and test...

Answer (score 1):

Welcome aboard. The golden rule here is that the more details you give us, the better  that we can help you. From your profile, I am guessing that the software is browser based, but it helps if you tell us that.

Are there any desktop PC components (windows / Linux)? Andy handheld devices (Android/iOs)?

What are you trying to monitor? If it is network activity, then you probably can’t beat [Nagoios](https://www.nagios.com/).

This excellent (and free) software is stable, well supported (about 4,000 questions on https://stackoverflow.com/) and well documented .

Its key features are:

- System Monitoring
- Protocol Monitoring
- Application Monitoring
- Database Monitoring
- Log Monitoring
- Bandwidth Monitoring

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagios) :

>  Nagios /ˈnɑːɡiːoʊs/, now known as Nagios Core, is a free and open
>   source computer-software application that monitors systems, networks
>   and infrastructure. Nagios offers monitoring and alerting services for
>   servers, switches, applications and services. It alerts users when
>   things go wrong and alerts them a second time when the problem has
>   been resolved.
>
>  Nagios was originally designed to run under Linux, but it also runs
>   well on other Unix variants. It is free software licensed under the
>   terms of the GNU General Public License version 2 as published by the
>   Free Software Foundation.

Read more there and on the Nagios web site.

Since your question is ***extremely*** broad, you might have meant to ask something else. If so, please update your question and we will do our best to help you.